# How do I take control of creation of the "navigator" of my UISplitView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I want control over the left hand side of my UISplitView. For now I just want to control the creation, so I'm able to set the UITableViewStyle. But I also want to know how the heck I can use a different class to UITableView altogether.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to get control over the default behaviour, but dragging a component into the left-hand side of the UISplitViewController in Interface Builder does the trick.

Not sure how you would tell the system not to create the default UITableView if you were going to populate it programmatically on viewDidLoad tho :-(